# Is there way to verify the request sent to API and the response back on click of a page element?

Tags: node.js, typescript, protractor

During the UI test, after clicking a button is it possible to verify if the right request is sent and the right response returned from the API using Node.js+Protractor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a way, at least in chrome browser, not sure about the others, but it's very long and complicated

1. You'll need to pass these to your browser from config file

```
chromeCapabilities.chromeOptions.perfLoggingPrefs = {
        enableNetwork: true,
        enablePage: false,
        traceCategories: 'browser,devtools.timeline,devtools',
    };
    chromeCapabilities.loggingPrefs = {
        performance: 'ALL',
        browser: 'ALL',
    };
```

2. Get the logs

```
let logs = await browser
        .manage()
        .logs()
        .get('performance');
```

3. Filter them to find what you are looking for. The logs you get from #2 will include requests you send, responses you got back and many more, so this is the most difficult part to find you need

If you intend to test the API response, I would have dedicated API tests for this isntead of doing it in protractor